# Mac listening on port 80 for both IPv4 127.0.0.1 and IPv6 ::1 with SSH tunnel, but connection is not possible with IPv4?

Tags: macos, http, ipv6, localhost, ssh-tunnel

I am connecting with openssh to a remote server, running a web server which I need to access as if from the server itself. Therefore I use ssh-tunneling, like this:

```
sudo ssh -L 80:127.0.0.1:7065 me@remote.server
```

On my Mac, netstat now shows:

```
$ netstat -na|grep 80.*LIST
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.80           *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  ::1.80                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

(And I verified that before, nothing listened on these ports.)
However, if I try to connect with telnet to 127.0.0.1 port 80, I get this:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

If I connect to ::1 (IPv6) instead, I get a connection as expected. Adding -4 to the IPv4 telnet command made no difference.

I discovered this, because I had only added the name of the server in /etc/hosts with the address 127.0.0.1 and not for ::1, thus access from a browser failed. Adding the name for ::1 solved the immediate problem with navigating the site from a browser, but I am still puzzled by this problem, and have been unable to find the cause.

I am using Mac OS X 10.8.5.

Addendum: I just tried forwarding a different service (port 22, SSH) to various local ports (including port 25, another privileged port) on my machine. All worked fine except port 80. So this seems to be an oddity related to port 80 on my machine.

Comment: Have you checked the machines firewall?

Comment: Thank you richard, I just thought of that myself (this is a machine I have "inherited" from a colleague, btw.) And sudo ipfw flush fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same Problem.

One solution was to not use port 80 but port 23

the other was to disable the Stealthmode (enable answering on icmp requests).

hope this helps